# datagrid check box column enable disable by row and cell

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried many approaches, but none of them work for me. I have a wpf datagridcheckbox column - if the checkbox of current row in column1 is checked, 
then current row's second column checkbox will be enabled... and other checkbox of that column should be disabled.

Similar to the image at the top of [this page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31829/Disabled-Checkbox-Column-in-the-DataGridView).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Might I suggest reading through this article on how to ask good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask As it is right now, it would be difficult for someone to reproduce your problem. Also, if you need to add images you can add them directly to your question instead of linking to a different site.

Comment: In addition to what @TJRockefeller said, we also need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't tell you how to fix your code if you have not posted it.

Comment: Okay I will improve my skills to post a question and will share code shortly